# How to pass date parameter inside the oracle procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the sample procedure code,

```
create or replace procedure pro_test(start_date date, end_date date)
is 
begin

insert into test1 select col1, col2, col3 from main where range_date between start_date and end_date;

exception

< what are the exception I need to capture >

end;
/
```

Q1 : Is this right way to pass date directly inside the procedure?
Q2 : If not, can I pass varchar inside the procedure , to convert the date in declaration part?
Q3 : In begin part am using between operator, can i pass procedure parameter directly ?

While executing this procedure, `exec pro_test('10102015','30102015');` What i need to mention in between sentence? between start_date and end_date is this enough or i need to mask date format?

can someone help me to clear on this?

Comment: yes you can pass date parameter directly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Q1 : Is this right way to pass date directly inside the procedure?

Yes.

> Q3 : In begin part am using between operator, can i pass procedure parameter directly ?

Not sure what you mean by this, but your insert statement is fine. You are passing a **DATE** as parameter and inserting into the table.

In my opinion, all this could be done in a single **INSERT..SELECT** statement in pure **SQL**.

```
insert into test1 
select col1, col2, col3 
from main 
where range_date 
between TO_DATE(<date_literal>,<format mask>)
and TO_DATE(<date_literal>,<format mask>);
```

---

**UPDATE** Per OP's comment:

> While executing this procedure, exec pro_test('10102015','30102015');
>   What i need to mention in between sentence? between start_date and
>   end_date is this enough or i need to mask date format?

`'10102015'` is not a DATE, it is a string literal. You must pass it as DATE, so you must either use **TO_DATE** with proper format mask or **ANSI Date literal** as you do not have any time portion. ANSI Date literal uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

For example,

Using **TO_DATE**:

```
EXEC pro_test(TO_DATE('10102015','DDMMYYYY'),TO_DATE('30102015','DDMMYYYY'));
```

Using **ANSI Date literal**:

```
EXEC pro_test(DATE '2015-10-10', DATE '2015-10-30');
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit. while executing this procedure,exec pro_test('10102015','30102015'); What i need to mention in between sentence? between start_date and end_date is this enough or i need to mask date format?

Comment: @BalaS You must pass a DATE, see the update in the answer.

Comment: @BalaS Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: I have changed code like this where caluse "where range_date between to_date(start_date,'ddmmyyyy') AND to_date(end_date,'ddmmyyyy')" and i executed my procedure (exec pro_test('10102015','10122016')), but am getting "literal does not match format string" error. I'm doing any wrong here?

Comment: @BalaS Are you sure your table doesn't have any column as start_date and end_date? Because I don't see any issue `SELECT to_date('10102015','ddmmyyyy') FROM dual;` runs perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1.** You need say procedure what type of parameters **input** or **output**(adding **in** or **out**), for your procedure it is input:

`create or replace procedure pro_test(start_date in date, end_date in date)`

Everything else in your procedure fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't *need* to specify parameter modes unless you want `OUT` or `IN OUT` -- `IN` is the documented default: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BCFHBGBI

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be extra cautious, you should namespace your pl/sql variables when they are used in a SQL statement:

```
create or replace procedure pro_test(start_date date, end_date date)
is 
begin

  insert into test1
  select col1, col2, col3
  from main where range_date
  between pro_test.start_date and pro_test.end_date;
...
```

This prevents the SQL engine "capturing" the variables if their name is the same as a column in a referenced table.

Commonly you see people try to avoid this with:

```
create procedure my_procedure (p_customer_id number)
...
where customer_id = p_customer_id
```

Namespacing the variables allows you to keep a cleaner interface without the prefixing.